# Android Activity transition - ListView dividers are visible too long

Tags: android, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop, activity-transition, shared-element-transition

During my exploration of Activity Transitions I've have encountered problem with ListView (unfortunately I've not migrated to RecyclerView yet :( )

ListView default dividers are visible for really short time (see video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHZCzQF3XOg&spfreload=10 ) during transition.

I've no idea why it is happening and how to make it stop doing this. Or maybe it is time to migrate to RecyclerView ;-)?

Comment: The dividers are drawn by the ListView, rather than the items themselves, so any property that's animated differently for the ListView itself versus the contained items would result in behavior like this.

Comment: @alanv ListView items are not shared elements so for me ListView items and dividers should animate in the same way.

Comment: Ah! If you want the ListView to animate together, set  transitionGroup="true" on the ListView. It will then move and animate as one. Otherwise the elements of the LIstView will animate separately. ViewGroups typically default to false, but when there is a background will switch to true so that you don't see a background turd left in the scene after the transition.

Comment: @GeorgeMount thanks! It was it! Please add answer so I will be able to mark it as a solution. Cheers and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the ListView to animate together, set transitionGroup="true" on the ListView. It will then move and animate as one. Otherwise the elements of the LIstView will animate separately. ViewGroups typically default to false, but when there is a background will switch to true so that you don't see a background turd left in the scene after the transition.